# Win xp hibernate timer

Tags: timer, windows-xp, hibernation

I've been trying to create a .bat file with the cmd - %windir%\system32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate.

I´m doing this because I want to keybind it. My problem is, that I would like to add a timer to the cmd, so that it will be executed in 30 min.

I´ve been looking all around for an answer, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using at? (or schtasks for the newer Windows versions)

```
at 00:00 cmd /c copy C:\Documents\*.* C:\MyDocs
```